# Avoid message "The Invantive Excel functions can only be installed when you have exactly one active Excel process."

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control

During startup of Excel I sometimes receive the following message:

> The Invantive Excel functions can only be installed when you have
>   exactly one active Excel process.
>
> Please end all 2 Excel processes through by closing all visible Excel
>   applications or by terminating all your Excel process in the Details
>   tab of Task Manager. Then restart Excel. You can also reboot your PC
>   or server.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Invantive Control uses a file "Invantive Control functions.xlam" located in your add-ins folder. It automatically repairs that file when the associated signature "Invantive Control functions.xlam-sig" or the file date indicate that it is a version not identical to the version managed by the COM Add-in part of Invantive Control.

You can see it here that there are actually two add-ins: one with the Excel functions and the backend as a COM add-in:

[image: Two add-ins]

When a repair is deemed necessary, the Invantive Control COM Add-in will try to replace the XLAM file.

However, Excel has the bad habit of not ending it's processes always correctly. So there can be one or more excel.exe active without an Excel window visible.

As the error describes you will need to inspect the presence of EXCEL.exe processes first and kill where no longer needed.

Or reboot your PC :-)